# PyCharm STDOUT window

Tags: python, pycharm

I just installed PyCharm Community Edition (v2017.1.2) on macOS 10.12.4. I can run and debug fine but I can't figure out how to view `STDOUT` during a debugging session. Searching for similar issues I found that I should have the Run window open. This is how I have my windows setup but nothing shows up. Am I doing this wrong? TIA

[image: *enter image description here*]

Comment: At the bottom ... the tab that says console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your picture you can see `console`.

All the output goes to there.

Comment: Son of a b*tch! ;-) Thank you!

Comment: For me, it opens IPython interactive console, which has nothing to do with running processes from Run/Debug buttons. Any ideas?